# Powershell to assign URLs to a variable instead of having them in a file

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell script to measure connectivity to a website, actually, part of the code is presented here. The PowerShell script will read a file called website.txt with few URLs (2 in this case) and will check connectivity time for them.

```
$URLListFile = $PSScriptRoot + "\websites.txt" 

$path_to_save = $PSScriptRoot + "\connection_test.html"

$URLList = Get-Content $URLListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

I would like to store the addresses in the code assigned to a single variable if possible and not in a file, so how can I do that there are several URL's listed in the code instead of the websites.txt and would go through all of them?

Comment: See `get-help ForEach -full` this may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a list:

```
$URLList = @(
    "www.url1.com", "google.com", "amazon.com"
)
```

or even simpler:

```
$URLList = "www.url1.com", "google.com", "amazon.com"
```

---

And now you can iterate over elements of this list:

```
$URLList | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "This is my url: $_" }

This is my url: www.url1.com
This is my url: google.com
This is my url: amazon.com
```

or using foreach

```
foreach ( $url in $URLList ) { Write-Host "Url is: $url" }

Url is: www.url1.com
Url is: google.com
Url is: amazon.com
```